# What's the name of the tool to bevel bar ends?

Tags: tools, mechanical

I noticed the mechanic at my LBS used a tool to smooth out and bevel the end of the steering tube after cutting it. It looks like a useful tool to smooth out the edge of bar ends as well. It's round and has a cone inside, what is it called? I don't have a picture unfortunately.

Comment: Do you mean a tubing reamer? http://www.homedepot.com/catalog/productImages/1000/d2/d22ec98f-4cab-489a-90d5-1858a23224f2_1000.jpg

Comment: @DanielRHicks The one in the picture is exactly right! Do you know if there is a tool like that made specifically for bike tubes?

Comment: Go to your local Menards or Home Despot and see if what they have looks like it would work.

Comment: Can I suggest tweaking the question?  I read it as meaning the tool to cut a corner off the bars for lock-on grips, whereas you're after a reburring tool for a flat straight cut.

Comment: @Criggie Feel free to edit the question, I can't find of a way to pose it without using "reburring" or "reamer" now :)

Comment: If it's just for bar ends run a half-round file without pressure around the inner edge followed by fine sanding paper.

Comment: Thanks @Carel. To be honest, it was mostly a curiosity, I don't have a specific use case for the tool in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the tubing is cut the cutting tool leaves a ridge in the inside of the tube. A reamer removes this rough edge or burr. It is hard to say if your mechanic used a bicycle specific reamer which may be part of a bearing facing tool or a generic deburring tool.